# invalid column name '...' SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get this red error when I add 1 column soluong?

And with such an error, when transmitting data, it will not transmit the soluong column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wuf6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t27d.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYkHq.png)

How to not get error when adding column?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your IntelliSense cache. In SSMS, go drill down through the menus for Edit --> ItelliSense --> Refresh Local Cache, or, press Ctrl + Shift + R. After initiating, wait a few seconds for those red errors to go away. Always initiate a refresh after altering objects if you don't want to view those red errors.